# Unable to get expected output using JOLT parser

Tags: java, jolt

I have below `input`:

```
[
  {
    "ownerId": "XTV7I728",
    "vehicleId": "999",
    "engines": [
      {
        "engineId": "1",
        "engineName": "Standard Engine",
        "engineHp": 300
      },
      {
        "engineId": "2",
        "engineName": "Custom Engine",
        "engineHp": 450
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I need the `expected` output as below:

```
    [{
      "ownerId": "XTV7I728",
      "vehicleId": "999",
      "engines":{
      "engineId": "1",
      "engineName": "Standard Engine",
      "engineHp": 300
}
    },
    {
      "ownerId": "XTV7I728",
      "vehicleId": "999",
"engines":{
      "engineId": "2",
      "engineName": "Custom Engine",
      "engineHp": 450
    }
}]
```

I tried below `spec` but it throws an error:

```
[{
  "ownerId": "ownerId",
  "*": {
    "vehicleId": "vehicleId",
    "engineId": "engineId",
    "engineHp": "engineHp"
  }
}]
```

`Error`:

```
Error running the Transform.

JOLT Chainr 'operation' must implement Transform or ContextualTransform at index:0.
```

Please let me know where I went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the operation (if using a Chain spec) and then a `spec` section that does the actual "walking" of your object tree. This should work:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "engines": {
          "*": {
            "@(2,ownerId)": "[#2].ownerId",
            "@(2,vehicleId)": "[#2].vehicleId",
            "*": "[#2].&"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Let me try it tomorrow morning. Also since I am new to this parser still pretty much confused with some of the concepts. Can you just explain spec especially the engine part. That would help actually. You can see I wasn't able to design such spec

Comment: I have modified my output. Can you help me to correct the output?

Comment: I know that `@` traverses backward and fetches the key at that level and `#` returns the value but I didn't get the last line `"*": "[#2].&"` as well as why ownerId and VehicleId are grouped in `@` tag?

Comment: I also understood one thing that if I remove # from the RHS then it would create array of values